# Can we refer to the field of the object validating in JSON schema to minLength property of the declared JSON schema?

Tags: javascript, json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Text",
  "description": "Form Text ",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "value": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "minLength":"this needs to point to fieldSpecific.minLength of the validating object"
    }
}
```

can we do something like this the object we receive to validate will be as below

```
{
  "fieldSpecific": {
    "minLength": 4
  },
  "value": "asfasfasfafasfasF"
}
```

in the above-received object we receive minLength under fieldSpecific can we write a JSON schema to refer minLength in field specific to validate the minLength of the value?

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema doesn't support this out of the box, but you can do it with [JsonSchema.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net/) and the extension [Data Vocabulary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net.Data/) package.

The docs can be found on [json-everything.net](https://json-everything.net/json-schema#a-vocabulary-for-accessing-data-stored-in-json).

Here's what your schema would look like with this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Text",
  "description": "Form Text ",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "value": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": "",
      "data": {
        "minLength": "/fieldSpecific/minLength"
      }
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: these libraries are mine.*